# What are these three circles on Google Flights website?

Tags: google-flights

What are these three circles on Google Flights website?

seen when trying to use the Google Flights website from my phone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These dates have been circled based on your date selection.

To understand these circle you need to know about your activity what you are doing.

You are looking for Round trip means two dates. In your case these are May 20 and May 27.
You selected May 20, it will show dark blue circle on May 20, then you selected May 27, dark blue circle moved to 27. May 20 is now white circle. It means whatever date you click in your selection it will show it with dark blue circle.

If you select One-way trip, it will show only one date with dark circle.

Third one circle (with blue outer color) that is May 25, is the circle you hover over mouse.

Comment: You wrote "You selected May 20," Do you mean I initially clicked on May 20th before clicking something else?  .   You write " then you selected May 27"  What did that do? Did that make the 27th my "to" date?   you write "dark blue circle moved to 27. "   So what does the dark blue circle mean? Does it mean my from date or my to date?  If it means my "to" date, then why is it that may 20th was you say initially a dark blue circle? If that's the case then what was my previous from date?

Comment: You write "whatever date you click in your selection it will show it with dark blue circle." <-- So does the dark blue circle have nothing to do with whether a date is the from date or the to date?

Comment: Yes, dark blue circle have nothing to do with whether a date is the from date or the to date.
You might have not clicked anywhere, you searched flight and by default it took two random dates and showed the result. So by default From date will be selected first and then To date will be selected. That's why dark blue circle is on To date. If you click on From date, dark blue circle move to From date. Basically it means it shows based on current activity.